# A quantifier for "there may exist" (for use in Set Builder notation)

Tags: quantifiers, alternative-set-theories

I have a dynamic situation consisting of two sets.  This situation occurs in my work so it’s not a theoretical or ‘strawman’ argument.

Let $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.  These sets could be joint or disjoint depending on whether they share a common element (or elements) which is unknown until the elements can be matched (i.e. there is no prior assumption as to whether or not there are any common elements).

I am trying to write the intersection of these sets using set builder notation.  At this stage, with my 'working' knowledge of set theory, I have come up with the following:

$$A \cap B = \{a,b \;|\;a \in A \; and \; b \in B,\; ∃a=b\}$$

However, this does not satisfy my situation as the existential quantifier (∃) means “there exists”, “there is at least one”, or “for some”.  In my dynamic situation the appropriate quantifier needs to mean “there $\pmb{may}$ exist”, “there may be at least $\pmb{none}$”, or “for $\pmb{maybe}$ some”.  Formalising the notation is important in order to help identify when the sets are not mutually exclusive as a stepping stone to further analysis.

Assuming it can be done, what is the best – and simplest – way to write this dynamic situation using set builder notation?

Comment: You seem to need some modal language. (That is, this is not an issue of the underlying set theory, but rather of the logical formalism in which you work.)

Comment: Maybe you should explain what is "dynamic" about your sets $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply :

> $A \cap B = \{ x \mid x \in A \text { and } x \in B \}$.

The formula reads : "the *intersection* of two sets $A$ and $B$ is the set of all and only those elements that belong to both $A$ and $B$."

The role of the set-builder notation $\{ x \mid \text { condition on } x \}$ is to specify that the set is formed by all and only those elements that satisy the *condition*.

To say that $A$ and $B$ are *disjoint*, we may use : $A \cap B = \emptyset$ that reads : "there is no common element between $A$ and $B$.

In formula : $\lnot \exists x \ (x \in A \cap B)$.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am aware of this is the classical set theoretic notation of an intersection - so maybe I am over thinking this problem and my question is trivial then.  However, it would be 'nice' to be able to have each set to be described by different symbols rather than $x$ for both of them. Again, probably over thinking this...

Comment: @MurrayB - something like : $x \in A \cap B \leftrightarrow (\exists a \in A \text { and } \exists b \in B \text { and } a=b \text { and } x =a)$ ?